# Firefox mobile navigator.maxTouchPoints is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-android

Regarding mobile device detection, various articles refer to using `navigator.maxTouchPoints`, including [this MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) :

> Use Navigator.maxTouchPoints to detect if the user's device has a touchscreen.

This method works great on most browsers, except for Firefox mobile on Android & iOS. It does however work on Firefox Focus though.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Johan_v_R/92tz3vdp/) to replicate the issue.

Is this a bug, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong..?